# Why is the result cleared in these special cases?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am trying to understand the solution to this Leetcode [question](https://leetcode.com/discuss/interview-question/1448681/morgan-stanley-assessment-question-identical-distribution).  The code is as follows:

```
int addCardSum = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < cardTypes.size(); i++){
    if(cardTypes[i]%2!=0)
addCardSum++;
}
if(addCardSum<2 || addCardSum==3)
    addCardSum=0;
return addCardSum;
```

It appears that this is a solution to divide into 2 matching packets (by the modulo of 2).  The math iterates over all card types, adding 1 on encountering any odd value.  This I understand.  What I don't get is the final check.  It clears out the count if the count is less than 2 or equal to 3.  What is going on here?  Aren't they valid values?

Comment: That code is very wrong but apparently passes the test cases.

Comment: I agree!  I am pulling my hair over this.  The clearing makes no sense to me.

Comment: Presumably the test cases "handled" by the special cases were ones where the optimal number of packets was not 2. E.g. if the input is $\{3,6,9\}$ then no cards need to be added since all the numbers are already divisible by 3 (so 3 packets can be created).

Comment: I suppose clearing is brute hack to pass all the tests.

Comment: Ahm ... Tailoring the system to pass the test, no matter what the real-life performance will be ... Why does that sound familiar? :)

Comment: Is it just me or does the linked-to question lack clarity and/or have severe typos?